# How do I lock down an applications access to only a specific list of indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch

Im looking at adding elasticsearch as a cache for some of my applications, however for security reasons I dont want other applications reading or messing with another applications indexes.

As far as i'm aware while hunting through kibana and other places online I cant find any solutions for this.

The documentation on elasticsearch years ago used to be an easier read. Now unfortunately its like hunting through spaghetti. are there any good solutions for restricting access in elasticsearch?

Note: xpack is enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can configure access down to index level (and beyond) using roles.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/defining-roles.html

I assume that you have [enabled security features](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/get-started-enable-security.html) and [configured passwords for built-in users](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/get-started-built-in-users.html). I will use `elastic` user to perform administrative tasks (though I believe you could use Kibana UI to do it instead).

First, create a role with access to `my-app-index` and `cache-*` indices.

```
curl -u elastic -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  http://localhost:9200/_security/role/my_app_role \
  -d '{"indices": [{"names": ["my-app-index", "cache-*"]}]}'
```

Then, create an application user and assign it to that role.

```
curl -u elastic -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  http://localhost:9200/_security/user/my_app_user \
  -d '{"password": "passw0rd", "roles": ["my_app_role"]}'
```

Now you can use that user to access only specified indices. The following requests will work:

```
curl -u my_app_user http://localhost:9200/my-app-index/_search
curl -u my_app_user http://localhost:9200/cache-1/_search
curl -u my_app_user http://localhost:9200/cache-2/_search
```

But this one, to another index, will return error:

```
curl -u my_app_user http://localhost:9200/another-app-index/_search
```